# Swift5 CoreStore CoreStore.fetchAll() throws error

Tags: swift, core-data, swift5, corestore

I'm using `CoreStore` Wrapper of CoreData with `Swift 5`

```
import CoreStore

@objc(Post)
public class Post: NSManagedObject {

}

extension Post {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Post> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Post>(entityName: "Post")
    }

    @NSManaged public var detail: String?
    @NSManaged public var sync: Server?
    @NSManaged public var time: Time?

}

extension Post {
    static var allPosts: [Post] {
        var posts :  [Post] = []
        do {
            posts = try CoreStore.fetchAll(From<Post>().tweak({ $0.includesPendingChanges = false }))
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return posts
    }
}
```

Fetching all data using.

```
let posts = Post.allPosts
```

Getting below error.

> ⚠️ [CoreStore: Error] From.swift:155
>   applyToFetchRequest(_:context:applyAffectedStores:)   ↪︎ Attempted to
>   perform a fetch but could not find any persistent store for the entity
>   
>       (CoreStore.CoreStoreError) .persistentStoreNotFound (
>       .errorDomain = "com.corestore.error";
>       .errorCode = 8;
>       .entity = Post; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve using fetching data into main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
   let posts = Post.allPosts 
}
```